# Deleting Gridview rows using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function to clear my form which includes a gridview, I previously tried another way to delete the rows without postback but somehow when I tried to add a new row, all the previous bounce back. Maybe I am using viewstate to maintain my gridview, not too sure but below is what I am doing which works well but somehow it only deletes one row, I guess probably when the postback occurs, the loop got wiped out. Any advice? I need the loop to delete all my gridview rows. Thanks!

```
 for (i = 0; i < camGv.rows.length; i++) {
                window.__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$gvCamVoucher', 'Delete$0');
            }
```

Comment: can i know how do you bind your grid view do you add the rows directly or just bind it to a datatable ? i have an answer for you but please i need more explanation

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I am binding it to a datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, I clear the gridview rows from code behind and use an Update Panel to group the grid so that the postback do not in any way affect my other fields.

Answer (score 3):

Well i think you need 2 things

1- A Way to Delete Your Rows from the Grid in the Client Side

2- A way to make that deletion effect on the server side just in case you made any postbacks 
to stay in your deletion state

1- you can catch the grid view in the client side with id and clear the all  inside its  execpt if there is a footer  that have the paging like this code

```
document.getElementById('grid view id').getElementsByTagName('TBODY').innerHTML='';
```

this line of script deletes all your rows thats if you dont have a footer grid pager

2- you have to make an ajax call to contact with the server and make the real effect if that table is have some thing from the database i think u need a delete function to delete all the rows from the database , if that is just a temp table have nothing to do from the database so i suggest to put it inside a Session that you can access the session in the ajax call

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //web method path
        url: "pageName.aspx/webmethodName",
        data: "{action:'delete'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) 
           {
           }
        ,error: function(error)
           {
           }
});
```

ASP.NET CS

```
[WebMethod]

public string DeleteAll(string action)
{
//you have to put the table from the begining where ever you initialize the data on it inside a session
DataTable dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["tbl"];
dt.Rows.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session["tbl"]=dt;
}
```

Regards 
please any question ask me :)

Comment: please tell me is that the answer you need or you do something else because if there is something else please describe to me to give you more help